# Remove padding in img src

Tags: html, css

Hay guys .

I have proble with img(src) . I want to remove the padding, but is not work.

This is my css :

```
.iconImage {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: block;
padding: -100px;

}
```

my img(src) have a class .iconImage .

but the image look like this. I can not remove the yellow box area  . See my print screen .

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I forget my html. this is my html :

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
<?php $id = $row['id']; ?><p class="searchView" >
<?php echo " <img class='iconImage' src='images/".$row['image']."' > " ?>
<a class="searchView" href="viewProfil.php?id=<?=$id; ?>" >
<?php echo $row['fullname'];?></a></p>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Please help me, and thank you so much !!

Comment: include you html code as well

Comment: hey,. my html is already in pic ... help me please :)

Comment: Please add your html here

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve] first of all, and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                  <?php $id = $row['id']; ?>
                  <p class="searchView" >
                   <?php echo " <img class='iconImage' src='images/".$row['image']."' > " ?>
                   <a class="searchView" href="viewProfil.php?id=<?=$id; ?>" >
                    <?php echo $row['fullname'];?>
                   </a>
                  </p>
         <?php endwhile;?>

Comment: @dnysaz use the `snippet` button to insert the code, or just `code` button

Comment: oke guys.. the html already include in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's margin not padding

try `margin:0` and `!important` if necessary.

And you look like putting the img in another div or something like that

Comment: many many thanks .. :) :) :) it work... thank you so much !!!!!!!!!
why im thinking is padding , oh my god .. :v

Answer (score 0):

> [Negative padding values not allowed](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_padding.asp)

`padding: -100px;` is invalid css property. try `padding: 0 !important` to test if this work, then remove `!important` and choose right [specificity](http://specificity.keegan.st/) for the rule selector

Comment: @dnysaz negative padding make no sense when you know what padding are. You can eventually use negative margin but it's risky.